# when to use a URN for xmlns

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

For a "hello world" type xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- see http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/ -->
<bk:book xmlns:bk="urn:loc.gov:books" xmlns:isbn="urn:ISBN:0-395-36341-6">
  <bk:title>Cheaper by the Dozen</bk:title>
  <isbn:number>1568491379</isbn:number>
</bk:book>
```

you can arbitrarily define urn's on the fly for custom purposes?

Comment: reall, why does this website not allow xml to part of the question? anyhow, the xml is at "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#scoping"

Comment: You need to format the code by indenting it with four spaces.  (Or by clicking the Format Code button in the toolbar)

Comment: doh, format code... thanks for fixing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, yes.  You can make 'em up as you like.

Comment: "[A URN namespace is identified by a "Namespace ID", NID, which is registered with IANA](https://www.w3.org/TR/uri-clarification/#urn-namespaces)", see [IANA-Registered Uniform Resource Names (URN) Namespaces](http://www.iana.org/assignments/urn-namespaces/urn-namespaces.xhtml)

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Name#Namespaces) (and RFC 3406) URN namespaces must remain globally unique and are therefore required to be registered with IANA. There is an exception for namespaces intended only for use within internal or limited experimental contexts. These namespaces are prefixed with `X-` and are not required to be unique.

Comment: @brianary, an *Excel* file saved as *XML table 2003* has the following namespace: `xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"`. I can't seem to find it in IANA... Have you an idea where the it is published?

Comment: @Ant_222 It sounds like that may be part of ECMA-376. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML

Comment: No, *OOXML* is a much newer format than that. I seem, however, to have found the [specification](http://m8y.org/Microsoft_Office_2003_XML_Reference_Schemas/SpreadsheetML_Schemas/) at a very strage site `m8y.org`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595141/xsd-file-where-to-get-xmlns-argument/2595172#2595172) quite useful, and it led me to [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-namcar.html) which seems to say that yes you can make them up as you like, and indeed you SHOULD, if you aren't going to place a document online for a given URL.

Comment: I can't find anything in that article that says you can make up your own URN NID. I don't think the example is meant literally.