# Intellij + Wildfly + jboss-ejb3.xml + xmlns:s="urn:security" "URI is not registered"

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, configuration, wildfly-8

I created the following jboss-ejb3.xml, which is located in WEB-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss:ejb-jar
    xmlns:jboss="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:s="urn:security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_2.xsd"
    version="3.2">
    <assembly-descriptor>
        <s:security>
            <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
            <s:security-domain>MySecurityDomain</s:security-domain>
        </s:security>
    </assembly-descriptor>
</jboss:ejb-jar>
```

Intellij IDEA 13.1.2 is giving me a validation error at `xmlns:s="urn:security`".  The error message is as follows:

*URI is not registered (Settings|Project Settings|Schemas and DTDs)*

It's not clear how to register `urn:security` via Settings|Project Settings|Schemas and DTDs because IDEA seems to want to know where the file is that the URI points to.  How does one register an "on-the-fly" URI (e.g. one with a urn: prefix) in IDEA?

Comment: It appears that `urn:security` is fine, that it's allowed to be made up on the fly.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4116282/984932) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2595172/984932).  I just would like to make the error message go away in Intellij when I open jboss-ejb3.xml in Intellij.